# VBA Macro - streamline

Tags: excel, vba, loops, locking, unlock

I need help. I am working with an excel doc that has over 200 rows and 25 columns. The code below attempts to lock and unlock data from row F3 and columns G, H, I, and J3. Is there a way to clean the code and have the code do this process for all rows F3:F200? I am trying to avoid having to do the code for each row (e.g., F4 and rest of the code, then F5 and so on). Any ideas anyone?

Many thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="code"

    If Range("F3") = "Yes" Then
    Range("G3").Locked = False
    Range("H3").Locked = False
    Range("I3").Locked = False
    Range("J3").Locked = False

    ElseIf Range("F3") = "No" Then
    Range("G3").Locked = True
    Range("H3").Locked = True
    Range("I3").Locked = True
    Range("J3").Locked = True

    End If



    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="code"

  End Sub

  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  End Sub
```

Comment: What if the user clears the value from column F ?  Should that change the locked status on that row?  Are there any possible values other than Yes/No/{blank} ?

Comment: To clarify, the code works as is. I am wondering if there is a way to avoid having to code every row (every F3, F4 and so on) and subsequent G, H, I, J all the way through 200 rows and 25 columns.

Initially, I played with the concept of telling excel – If Range("F3:F200") and Range("G3:G200") - would this work to accomplish what I need? And it did not. So, I am here hoping someone would have already found a way to do this. By the way, thank you Tim for fixing the code. Bad copy and pasting on my part. : -)

Comment: OMG!!! I am forever grateful!!! Your code worked. I will now examine the script and learn from what you have provided. Thank you, TIM. A+++

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range, v

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="code"

    For Each c in Range("F3:F200")
        v = c.Value
        If v = "Yes" or v = "No" then
            c.Offset(0,1).Resize(1,4).Locked = (v = "No")
        End If
    Next c

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="code"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick rewrite that loops down all the range... my only question was, is there a yes/no in every row to indicate the locked/unlocked?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
For i = 1 To 200
    If Cells(i + 2, 6) = "yes" Then
        Range(Cells(i + 2, 7), Cells(i + 2, 10)).Locked = False
    ElseIf Cells(i + 2, 6) = "no" Then
        Range(Cells(i + 2, 7), Cells(i + 2, 10)).Locked = True
    End If
Next i
ActiveSheet.Protect

  End Sub
```